# Object.defineProperty for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, defineproperty

Asking about Object.defineProperty as demonstrated below:

```
function testComponent(){
    var testProperty;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "testProperty",
    {
        get : function()
        {
           return testProperty;
        },
        set : function(val)
        {
          testProperty = val;
        }
    });
}
```

Where it would be used like so:

```
testObject = new testComponent();
testObject.testProperty = "testValue";
```

Based on what I've seen so far, it looks like there is no cross browser solution, as I've tried using **[es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)** with no luck, but I would like to confirm.  I also found a reference to  **[this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/07/transitioning-existing-code-to-the-es5-getter-setter-apis.aspx)** and my tests still fail in IE 7 & 8, can anyone shed any light on this?

I remember looking through a related question a few months ago somewhere on S/O and I think I saw someone had written a solution for this in an answer.  Any general workarounds for getter / setters would also be appreciated.  The idea is that I need some equivalent of a getter setter on an object without passing the parameter change through a method.  I don't need IE6, but I would like to support browsers in the range of IE7+ ff 3.6+ , etc

---

### QUnit tests below: (*jsFiddles*)

(these pass in all browsers on my machine except IE 7 & 8

**direct use of defineProperty, no shims**: 
 http://jsfiddle.net/uSYFE/

**fiddle using the ES5 shim, I'm assuming all I need to do is include it?**  :
 http://jsfiddle.net/hyperthalamus/ntwDy/

**fiddle using the IE recommended solution** :
 http://jsfiddle.net/hyperthalamus/xfvz3/

Comment: right now my Qunit tests are in my environment. I've imported the shims and IE7 / 8 is still failing while the rest of my browsers are passing.  I'm just getting an error on using "Object.defineProperty".   I'll see if I can create an isolation test.  (I should have done that in advance)

Comment: Edited my question with the specifics

Comment: if only jsfiddle worked in IE8 :-(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim):

> /!\ Object.defineProperty
>
> This method will silently fail to set "writable", "enumerable", and "configurable" properties.
>
> Providing a getter or setter with "get" or "set" on a descriptor will silently fail on engines that lack "defineGetter" and "defineSetter", which include all versions of IE up to version 8 so far.
>
> IE 8 provides a version of this method but it only works on DOM objects. Thus, the shim will not get installed and attempts to set "value" properties will fail silently on non-DOM objects.
>
> https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/issues#issue/5

So you know your answer. It can be done on DOM elements, that's it (and on IE8 only).

I'd suggest you just use get/set methods if you want IE7 to work.

Answer (score 2):

For older IEs you'd have to make sure your property is a dom object (even a fake tag) and use onPropertyChange to get notified.  See this post by [John Dyer](http://johndyer.name/native-browser-get-set-properties-in-javascript/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same question myself. [(See here.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106936/cross-browser-getter-and-setter) It doesn't look like it's fully possible in IE8 or lower. Otherwise the [ES5 Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) is your best bet.