# how to emit events from a factory

Tags: angularjs

How can I emit events from a factory or service. I am unable to inject $scope into the factory, thus unable to emit events.

I get the following error -  `Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope`

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: Why not watch a service variable in the controller(s) instead of emitting events?

Comment: @AndersBornholm the watch functy in angular is triggered with every digest cycle. Digest cycles can happen quite often depending on the app. Pubsub offers better communication channel. It does not need to eval with every digest cycle.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You cannot inject a controller's scope into a service. What you can do is:

- pass the scope instance as a parameter to one of your service functions:

e.g.

```
app.factory('MyService', function() {

   return {
      myFunction: function(scope) {
         scope.$emit(...);
         ...
      }
    };
});
```

- inject the $rootScope into your service:

e.g.

```
app.factory('MyService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

   return {
      myFunction: function() {
         $rootScope.$emit(...);
         ...
      }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Would'nt I do a broadcast from rootscope?

Comment: I think this is the only way to emit event upwards so that same level controllers don't catch emitted event - if that's what you want (it was in my case)

Comment: @murtaza52 You really want to avoid broadcasting. See [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19498009/1195050)

Comment: Not sure is the right way, this may create a leak when controller is destroyed, what happen to this $scope object?

Comment: @Thomas Decaux I wouldn't use events in the first place (injecting services is the better way), but if you don't keep references to `scope`, it shouldn't create memory leaks

Answer (score 59):

Inject $rootScope instead of $scope and then emit it on the $rootScope.

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$emit("myEvent", myEventParams);
}]);
```

Factories don't have access to the current controller/directive scope because there isn't one. They do have access to the root of the application though and that's why $rootScope is available.

Comment: This is the correct answer, Factory must not depend to a controller, since their live cycle is totally different.

Answer (score -1):

In your factory inject $rootScope as-

```
myApp.factory('myFactory',function($rootScope){
return({
// use $rootScope as below to pass myEventParams to all below in hierarchy
$rootScope.$broadcast("myEvent",myEventParams);

})
}]);
```

Comment: I really do not understand voting an answer as not useful without giving proper justification . Highly Unprofessional .

Comment: Well your answer is basically a duplicate of the 5 year old answers above it and doesn't add anything whilst also being less clear than the two existing accepted answers. What information did you think you were adding?