# How to detect variable change events between controllers

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a fairly trivial notification system where I want a main menu (outside ng-view) to display the last activity of the user, from what I've read it looks like a service is best used to communicate between controllers. How should I detect when something happens in controller A **immediately** from controller B. Should I $watch the variable of the service? Or is there an easier way to do this? Or given should I just have a root scope variable and $watch and change that with the controllers?

Comment: I am new to AngularJS, but maybe you should take a look at `emit`/`broadcast` functionality for loose coupling of your controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$broadcast` and `$on` methods. [Here's a good example](http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/) found on the internet

Also, there is no more an issue with `$broadcast` over `$emit` in recent versions of angular,  because `$broadcast` runs as fast as `$emit`.

Don't use $watch for this because it will create a  lot of events ( angular has also a limit of 10 rerun iterations to prevent deadlock ).

> The watch listener may change the model, which may trigger other listeners to fire.
>   This is achieved by rerunning the watchers until no changes are
>   detected. The rerun iteration limit is 10 to prevent an infinite loop
>   deadlock.

Read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 0):

$watch will trigger everytime your variable change. Your can use $emit or $broadcast with $on for a less regular event.
This can be done in a factory : [how to emit events from a factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056874/how-to-emit-events-from-a-factory)

Answer (score 0):

Could store something in the global $window and create a watch expression on it, that is just off the top off my head, might be a better way to do it.

Also take a look at this as it is like the sort of thing you need to do:

[Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers)