# Communication between modules in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I guess it is possible to have many angular-modules attached to different regions within one shellpage.
But can modules in AngularJS "talk" to each other?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are various ways module can interact or share information

1. A module can be injected into another module, in which case the container module has access to all elements of the injected module. If you look at [angular seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project, modules are created for directive, controllers, filters etc, something like this

   angular.module("myApp", ["myApp.filters", "myApp.services", "myApp.directives", "myApp.controllers"])
   This is more of a re usability mechanism rather than communication mechanism.
2. The second option is as explained by @Eduard would be to use services. Since services are singleton and can be injected into any controller, they can act as a communication mechanism.
3. As @Eduard again pointed out the third option is to use parent controller using $scope object as it is available to all child controllers.
4. You can also inject $rootScope into controllers that need to interact and use the $broadcast and $on methods to create a service bus pattern where controllers interact using pub\sub mechanism.

I would lean towards 4th option. See some more details here too [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Comment: I am going to go with the 4th option. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here (on no. 4 to be more specific). The documentation states that each app has its own `$rootScope`. When you say that the `$rootScope` needs to be injected, do you mean that the `$rootScope` from `firstModule` needs to be injected into the controller of the `secondModule`?

Comment: app is not module. Generally the is only one app, with multiple modules in it. `$rootscope` is shared across modules in a single app.

Answer (score 3):

Using the service mechanism to communicate among module's controllers.

```
 (function () {
        'use strict';

    //adding moduleB as dependency to moduleA

    angular.module('Myapp.moduleA', ['Myapp.moduleB'])
      .controller('FCtrl', FCtrl)
      .service('sharedData', SharedData);

    //adding the dependency shareData to FCtrl

    FCtrl.$inject = ['sharedData'];

    function FCtrl(sharedData) {

      var vm = this;
      vm.data = sharedData.data;
    }


    //shared data service
    function SharedData() {

      this.data = {
        value: 'my shared data'
      }

    }

    //second module
    angular.module('Myapp.moduleB', [])
      .controller('SCtrl', SCtrl);

    SCtrl.$inject = ['sharedData'];

    function SCtrl(sharedData) {

      var vm = this;
      vm.data = sharedData.data;
    }


    })();
```

And the HTML as follows:

```
<html ng-app="firstModule">
<body>

  <div ng-controller="FCtrl as xyz">
    <input type=text ng-model="xyz.data.value" />
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="SCtrl as abc">
    <input type=text ng-model="abc.data.value" />
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) and controllers inheritance (explained here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller)

in any case, you shuold consider not having your controllers tighlty coupled.

Comment: [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller) is broken can you fix it