# Share data, events across multiple angular modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing some project where I use multiple modules

I have a kernel module and other modules that depend on kernel

```
angular.module('kernel', []);
...
angular.('process-manager', [ 'kernel', 'ui.router' ])
...
etc
```

I need to share some data across all modules and also broadcast some events across all modules.

For now in child modules I'm using $rootScope of kernel module that defined as a global in the $window object

```
.factory('$appScope', appScope)
...
appScope.$inject = ['$window', '$rootScope'];
function appScope($window, $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
    if (angular.isDefined($window.superScope) === false) {
        $window.superScope = $rootScope;
    }

    return $window.superScope;
}
```

Is there any better solution to do things like this?

**EDIT**
kernel module bootstraped through ng-app and other modules bootstraped through angular.bootstrap();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use local storage to pass data between modules and keep the data consistent . Here is a great example

http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/sharing-messages-and-data-across-windows-using-localstorage/

Comment: It's a good idea, but I steel believe that I can do it without localstorage.

Comment: I have used https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage and found it to be very useful for use with Angular.

Answer (score 2):

I see you're using `.factory()...` in your code, and even though I'm not sure exactly how you use it, you might be on the right path.

Use services. Services are singletons that are meant to hold data that can be shared through injection across your app and even across modules. As for broadcasting events, you can call `$broadcast` on your `$rootScope`, or you can `$watch` changes on your services' data in all modules.

There's a better answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17044577/1371131).

Here's an example:

```
angular.module('firstModule', []).service('MyService', function () {
  return {
    some: 'data'
  };
}).controller('someController', function ($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return MyService.some;
  }, function (some) {
    // This runs whenever the service's data changes
    console.log(some.data, 'logged in first module');
  }, true);
});

angular.module('secondModule', ['firstModule']) // <-- this makes the first module's service available for injection in the second module
  .controller('someController', function ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
      return MyService.some;
    }, function (some) {
      // This runs whenever the service's data changes
      console.log(some.data, 'logged in second module');
    }, true);
  })
```

## Cum grano salis

The service may be instantiated anew for every module, which may impede your ability to communicate across modules. Please fact-check me on this. In the meantime, local storage as suggested in Dennis Nerush's answer may be the better way to go. I have found https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage to be a good complement for usage with Angular.

Comment: I'm using factory instead of service. It's not a same?

Comment: Not quite, but the difference is subtle, and it may work with factories as well. You may need to try it out. [Here](http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/)'s an explanation of the differences between services and factories (and providers).

Comment: I'll try to use services instead of factory and tell you about a result

Comment: It shouldn't matter. What's important is that you can inject a service from one module into another and watch its data. That's how all modules stay informed about the data.

Comment: For now angular creates one factory for each module, so if I store some data to kernel's factory called 'MyFactory' this data will not appear in child module factory 'MyFactory'...

Comment: Are you creating a second factory? You only need one and share it across modules.

Comment: No, I don't. I'm just watching events from factories.
$scope.$on('SomeEvent', ...);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104066/discussion-between-dchacke-and-vlad-kosko).

Answer (score 0):

Register an event listner in the required modules as '$scope.$on('changedVariable', function (event, args){//do your thing in listning module});'

And in the module from where you need to braodast:
$scope.$broadcast('changedVariable', { change: someValue});
And you are done, precisely! ;)

Comment: this will not work because I have a multiple bootstraped modules and each module has own $rootScope

Comment: Works for me even with multiple modules... And that is only when you use $broadcast instead of $emit while going across modules

Comment: I was tried it many times and it's not work. I can $broadcast event at 1 $rootScope but I can't $broadcast it on multiple $rootScopes