# calling controller of different module from one directory to another

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

On button click it goes to a controller and from that controller function I will have to call controller of another module which is in different directory. I tried using $rootscope boradcast and $rootscope.$on - it goes to boradcast but never makes to $rootscope.on method.

How can I communicate from one directory controller to another directory controller? Any help will be highly appreciated. I've attached sample code.

```html
folder structure webapp -> employee
//first controller
angular.module("employee")
.controller('controller1', controller1);
function controller1($rootscope, $scope){

//on button click comes to this function
$scope.empData = function(data){

//from here I need to call managercontroller managerHistory function

}

}


//folder structure webapp -> manager
//manager controller
angular.module('manager')[
.factory('$manager'), function(){

var managerdata ={
---
----
}

return managerdata;

}
.controller ('managercontroller', ['$rootscope', '$scope', function($rootscope, $scope){


//from employee controller1 i need to call this function
$scope.managerHistory = function(){



}

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communication between modules in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043804/communication-between-modules-in-angularjs)