# AngularJS: Sharing scope behavior with sibling or descendant scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to share scope behavior from one of my controllers higher up in my app hierarchy so that it's able to manage data from an unrelated/uninherited scope as a sort of abstract and separate 'remote control'?

This is how I have things setup in psudo-angular:

```
//Looking to share the ManagedScope1 and ManagedScope2 "changeChannel()" behavior with this controller
<RemoteControlCtrl>
  <ng-click="managedScope1.changeChannel()"></ng-click>
  <ng-click="managedScope2.changeChannel()"></ng-click>
</RemoteControlCtrl>

//ManagedScopes inherit ChangeChannelCtrl scope behaviors
<ChannelChangeCtrl with $scope.changeChannel() method>
  <ManagedScope1></ManagedScope1>
  <ManagedScope2></ManagedScope2>
</ChannelChangeCtrl>
```

The `$scope.changeChannel()` method is inherited in both managed scopes, and can act on their own data accordingly.

Comment: use services for that.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a ChannelService....

```
.service('ChannelService', function () {
    return {
        changeChannel: function (scopeData, callback) {
             //change the channel

             if (angular.isFunction(callback)) {
                  callback();
             }
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'ChannelService', function ($scope, ChannelService) {
     $scope.dataForChangingChannel = {};
     $scope.changeChannel = function () {
          //do UI stuff here

          ChannelService.changeChannel($scope.dataForChangingChannel, function () {
                //or UI stuff here, after the channel has been changed
          });
     }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depends on what kind of component that generated the scope.

If it is a completely unrelated scope, you should use `$broadcast`. You can require `$rootScope` as dependancies in remote controller and `$rootScope.$broadcast('eventName', someData)`. In your channel controller:

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function(event, data) {
    // Do something here
})
```

Another good idea would be using a service, but that would still be hard to call method on another scope. I would say event broadcasting is a nice approach for your problem.