# Angular JS variable hoisting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

given this http request:

```
    $scope.obj = {}

    $scope.loadTourInfo = function() {
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mirror.discoverhawaiitours.com/activity_object_json/11204.json'
      }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.obj = data;
    });
}
```

how can I pass the returned object (data) outside of my function's scope?

Comment: I don't think this is Angular specific, looks like this very common question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Isn't `poop = $scope.obj = data;` outside your function scope if `poop` is declared outside the function?

Comment: What elclanrs said; this has nothing to do with variable hoisting.

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with variable hoisting. `$scope` is within the success function's scope so what you're doing should work fine.