# AngularJS $scope value won't read in different controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, coffeescript, scope

I have a case where I need to ask for confirmation on deleting data in Angular, I did it with this (along with Angular UI Bootstrap):

```
    $scope.delete = (id) ->
        $scope.setId = id //here the $scope.setId is 543
        $modal.open
            templateUrl: 'deleteModalContent.html'
            controller: modalInstanceController

    modalInstanceController = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', ($scope, $modalInstance) ->
        $scope.delete_ok = ->
            console.log $scope.setId //here the value becomes undefined

        $scope.delete_cancel = ->
            $modalInstance.dismiss 'cancel'
    ]
```

As I have stated my problem in the code (on the comment), the id becomes undefined in different controller, without `$rootscope`, how can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this thread [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

You have to use the root scope to share the values, or a service.

Comment: And using the service is preferred solution for most cases.

Comment: I understand rootscope, but how does a service can help in this case?

Comment: A service is a singleton in Angular. If you use a service in your delete directive and also in the controller, you can expose a get and set for your setId in the service.

However in your case I would recommend to do $rootScope.$emit('deleteEventName', setId) and listen to this in your controller with $scope.$on('deleteEventName', function (setId) { .. }

Comment: @Stefan: ah i see, still using `$rootScope`, I thought It will be a solution where I don't have to use that. Thanks for the fiddle.