# Angularjs - Why I can update an object but not the list (ng-repeat) from a different view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

By the console the customers object seems updated, but the list(ng-repeat) not, what can i do. If I implement this funciont and view2.htm's html inside page.htm it works.

HTML "page.htm"

```
    <body ng-controller="simpleController">

<div ng-view></div>

<input ng-model="cust" type="text" />

<ul><li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:cust ">{{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}</li></ul>

<label for="_newname">Customer name:</label>
<input name="_newname" ng-model="_newname" type="text" />
```

HTML "view2.htm"

```
<label for="newname">Customer name:</label>
<input name="newname" ng-model="newname" type="text" />

<label for="newcity">Customer city:</label>
<input name="newcity" ng-model="newcity" type="text" />

<button ng-click="addNewCustomer()" >Add Customer</button>
```

Jvascript

```
var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", ["ngRoute"]);

demoApp.controller("simpleController", simpleController);

function simpleController($scope){
    $scope.customers = [
        {name : "Fulvio", city:"London" },
        {name : "Elisa", city:"Catanzaro" },
        {name : "Immacolata", city:"Catanzaro"},
        {name : "Vitaliano", city:"Roma"},
        {name : "Ivan", city:"Milano"}
    ];

    $scope.addNewCustomer = addNewCustomer.bind($scope);
}


demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.
        when("/",{
            controller: simpleController,
            templateUrl: "view2.htm",
        }).
        when("/second",{
            controller: simpleController,
            templateUrl: "view2.htm"
        }).
        when("/third",{
            controller: simpleController,
            templateUrl: "view3.htm"
        }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});

});

var addNewCustomer = function(){
    this.customers.push({name:this.newname, city:this.newcity});
}
```

Comment: You should probably broadcast between the two. Also, define addNewCustomer on $scope in your controller. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs

Comment: The controller is the same for all the viewes

Comment: The scopes are different each view. You need to broadcast the data from one to the other.

Comment: Ok I solved with $rootScope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike services, which are singletons, controllers are created freshly each time.

`<body ng-controller="simpleController">` creates a controller with a scope, that is used by your `ng-repeat` directive.

`when("/",{controller: simpleController,` creates yet another controller with its own scope and **its own** `customers` list, that you are adding to when the button is clicked. It's not the same list as in the parent controller.

I assume you want to use only one `simpleController` so don't add one to your routing definitions.

```
    $routeProvider.
    when("/",{
        // controller: simpleController, <- don't do this
        templateUrl: "view2.htm",
    }).
```

But you have something else to keep in mind: The way you define you `ng-model` sticks it to the scope of the view. The cleanest way imho is to write a separate controller for each view, that deals only with the view. That's the way it's meant to be, because `addNewCustomer` is only relevant for that view.

```
demoApp.controller('viewController', function($scope) {
  $scope.addNewCustomer = function(){
    $scope.customers.push({name:$scope.newname, city:$scope.newcity});
  }  
})

when("/",{
  controller: viewController,
  templateUrl: "view2.htm",
 }).
```

Comment: @Donovant Sorry, I thought I made it pretty clear. I added some code.

Comment: @Donovant It should. Set up a fiddle or plunkr or whatever, with your code and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: It shoud but it doesn't. If you assert that it works you've to set up a fiddle imo.

Comment: @Donovant Fair enough: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pb0wKcK6cpmNTAsTYpcJ). It works, but I guess you refer to another problem: `ng-model` is still in the child scope.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that you had created another controller...
But without creating another controller I've to use $rootScope.

Comment: @Donovant You have another option: create an object in your controller's scope, like `$scope.newCustomer= {}`, and in your view refer to that, like `ng-model="newCustomer.name"`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this.apply() to your addNewCustomer method...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using $rootScope
Html

```
<button ng-click="$broadcast('addNewCustomer')" >Add Customer</button>
```

Javascript

```
function simpleController($rootScope, $scope){

   $rootScope.customers = [
               {name : "Fulvio", city:"London" },
               {name : "Elisa", city:"Catanzaro" },
               {name : "Immacolata", city:"Catanzaro"},
               {name : "Vitaliano", city:"Roma"},
               {name : "Ivan", city:"Milano"}
   ];


   $scope.$on("addNewCustomer", function(){
        $scope.customers.push({name: $scope.newname, city: $scope.newcity});
        console.log( $rootScope.customers );
   });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.  I remade your controller so that the addNewCustomer function is within the same controller.

```
var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", ["ngRoute"]);

demoApp.controller("simpleController" function($scope) {

  $scope.customers = [
    {name : "Fulvio", city:"London" },
    {name : "Elisa", city:"Catanzaro" },
    {name : "Immacolata", city:"Catanzaro"},
    {name : "Vitaliano", city:"Roma"},
    {name : "Ivan", city:"Milano"}
 ];

 // You can do two things here, either pass in the customer object, 
 // OR bind to $scope.customer on your model

 $scope.addNewCustomer = function(customer){
   $scope.customers.push(customer);
 };

});


demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider.
    when("/",{
        controller: simpleController,
        templateUrl: "view2.htm",
    }).
    when("/second",{
        controller: simpleController,
        templateUrl: "view2.htm"
    }).
    when("/third",{
        controller: simpleController,
        templateUrl: "view3.htm"
    }).
    otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});

});
```

** Views

page.html

```
<!-- not sure what this input is for -->
<input ng-model="customer" type="text">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:cust ">
    {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}
  </li>
</ul>

<label for="_newname">Customer name:</label>
<input name="_newname" ng-model="_newname" type="text">
```

view2.html

```
<label for="newname" >Customer name:</label>

<input name="newname" ng-model="customer.name" type="text">

<label for="newcity">Customer city:</label>

<input name="newcity" ng-model="customer.city" type="text">

<button ng-click="addNewCustomer(customer)" >Add Customer</button>
```

Comment: Yeah your views are not set up to work with the code i posted.  Give me a moment to add the views to my answer.