# Angular ui-router nested views don't refresh data retrieved by Angular Services

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a nontrivial Angular SPA that uses ui-router to manage multiple views, many of which are visible at the same time. I need models to be visible across controllers, so I have services written that allow me to have controllers pull down fresh copies of model data that has been updated.

I apologize in advance for the length of the question, but I will state the problem then state what I have done to address issues I'm sure others in the Angular community have struggled with.

I believe my problem is not understanding the lifecycle of controllers / views, because I get behavior where a controller initializes correctly the first time I go there, but then seems to never run again, even when I navigate to it using something like `$state.go("state name")`.

In one view (contrived example), I show a summary of information about a customer, and in another view I allow a user to update that customer's more detailed profile. I want a user to edit, say, the customer last name in the detailed view, and have the summary view automatically recognize the change and display it.

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Px8U7/34/) that shows 3 views and a simple password changing Service. The flow goes like this:

1. You can see each view gets initialized and displays the initial password retrieved from the service. All views are in sync with the DataService.
2. The middle view allows you to enter a new password and change the one stored in the service. Console logging confirms that the service picks up the new password just like you would expect.
3. (odd behavior #1) When the DataService receives the new password, I would expect the other 2 views (top and bottom) to display the new one. They don't... they still display the initial password.
4. There is a button to allow a user to go to another `state` via `$state.go("state name")` (a child state of the original) which also retrieves the password and displays it. This works *the first time* (see #5). Now the top view shows the outdated password, the middle view shows the new one, and the bottom one shows the new one as well. This seems normal, since the new view is invoked after the DataService contains a new password value.
5. (odd behavior #2) If I click back in the middle view and change the password again, and click the button to change states again, the bottom view (which updated just fine in step #4) no longer updates its copy of the password. Now all 3 views show different passwords, even though I am using a single service to pass values between controllers as suggested pretty much everywhere you look for Angular best practices.

Some possible solutions:

- Tim Kindberg has an excellent slideshow [here](http://slid.es/timkindberg/ui-router) that seems to recommend using ui-router's *state heirarchy* to "pass" data among views that need to pick up values from other views. For a smaller-scale app I think I would settle on this, but I expect our application to have 30+ views displaying data from over 100 REST endpoints. I don't feel comfortable maintaining an application where all the data is being shared by a complex inheiritance tree. Especially using a routing framework that is at version **0.2.8**.
- I can use events to have controllers listen for changes in the data model. This actually works well. To accommodate performance concerns, I am using `$rootScope.emit()` and a `$scope.$onRootScope('event name')` decorator I found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs). With this approach I am less concerned about event performance than I am about wiring this huge app with a bunch of event listeners tying everything together. There is a question about the wisdom of wiring a large app using angular events [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416854/pros-cons-of-using-events-heavily-to-keep-controllers-in-sync-across-complex-ang).
- Using `$watch` on the value in the DataService? I have not tried this but I am hesitant to hinge an app this size on hundreds of `$watch`es for performances reasons.
- A third-party library like [bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js) (or any of a dozen others) that may simplify the event spaghetti, or create observable models that my controllers can watch without the risk of `$digest`ageddon. Of course, if there is a concise way to handle my issue using Angular, I'd prefer not to muddy the app with 3rd party dependencies.
- Something that lets controllers actually reference `.service` modules by reference, so I don't have to depend on tons of event wiring, complex state hierarchies, 3rd party libraries, or seeding the app with hundreds of `$watch`es and then kicking off `$digest`s to update controllers' references to Angular services?
- Some solution that relies on time-tested OO and design patterns and not a 3rd-party library or framework that has a version that starts with **0.***.

Thanks in advance... I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hh... ui.router starts with 0.x

Comment: @IlanFrumer Yes, which makes me nervous. We use it because we believe it is going to be the defacto routing solution for most complex SPA angular apps. We are trying not to hinge our app structure on very many ui-router utilities because we know they are going to change and mature. I can live with that. What I was referring to was bacon.js specifically (v 0.7.2 as of this writing) and any of the thousand github libraries that will never reach 1.0.

Comment: I don't believe this is a problem with ui.router. But one with primitives and references and their bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no problem of ui.router. If you intend for your model (your data service) to be a single source of truth, you have to refrain from destroying it.. err.. the reference to it that is. And in your case, assigning a primitve (a string) directly to the scope, instead of a reference to it. In other words...

```
var password = {pw:'initial value'};
```

and then later setting/binding only on

```
password.pw = newpassword

{{password.pw}}
```

Heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2CPC/16/). And also here is a short little read on scopes, It also includes a video of an angular meetup where Misko talks about "always have(ing) a dot in your model" [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) and how the `$scope` is a place to expose your model, not be your model. (aka not a place to assign primitives like `password = 'initial value'`)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this... I believe this is what I was missing, but I have a couple questions about your fiddle. When I inspect the DataService's password object after setting a new password, it has an endless set of nested pw objects... so something is screwy. Also, I want to be able to validate the input *before* it gets displayed in other views, so I don't want it to update live as I type. I'll read and play around, but if you know why I'm seeing those odd behaviors in your fiddle I'll accept this pronto! Thanks Caleb.

Comment: Woops, I didn't go through your fiddle very thoroughly. You might consider what you want to be a "Work In Progress" eg. non-validated changing values that you don't want to persist yet. So maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n2CPC/16/)

Comment: This is exactly it, and also really shows me how to avoid needing the event wiring from  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416854/pros-cons-of-using-events-heavily-to-keep-controllers-in-sync-across-complex-ang/21438782?noredirect=1#21438782). Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try remove the animation property of your ion nav view.
remove the property
animation="slide-left-right"

it would be ok.