# What is wrong with these $scope events suing $broadcast and $emit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

What I want is for `SubCtrl` to broadcast an event when it is loaded saying that it wants to get information. I want `MainCtrl` to be listening for a call to the `get` event and respond by broadcasting the 'set' event and providing its `name` property as an argument. The `SubCtrl` should be listening for the `set` event and respond by populating its own scopes `name` property.

With the following code, `MainCtrl` receives the `get` event, but `SubCtrl` never receives the `set` event.

### Script

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.$on('get', function(event) {
    console.log('get event received');
    $rootScope.$broadcast('set', $scope.name);
  })
});

app.controller('SubCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.name = '..waiting';
  $rootScope.$broadcast('get');
  $scope.$on('set', function(event, name) {
    console.log('set event received');
    $scope.name = name;
  });
});
```

### Markup

```
<body>
  <p ng-controller="MainCtrl">Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <p ng-controller="SubCtrl">Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I immediately realized the problem. I need to set the `$on` listener before I `$broadcast` the `get` event.

```
app.controller('SubCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.name = '..waiting';
  $scope.$on('set', function(event, name) {
    console.log('set event received');
    $scope.name = name;
  });
  $rootScope.$broadcast('get');
});
```

Comment: Does it work now? I'm surprised because `$broadcast` should be used to dispatch event to **child scopes** and `$emit` to dispatch to parent scopes (according to [$scope docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope)). If you want to communicate between controllers on sibling nodes, there are 2 ways: use a common parent controller or use a service, like a pub/sub service. I chose the second solution. If you want to try it, my angular-pubsub service is here: https://github.com/glepretre/angular-pubsub.

Comment: Hey that *is* a good idea! I will check that out. My code does work because I am `$broadcast`-ing from `$rootScope` and listening `$on` the local scope.

Comment: I'm glad you like the idea :) I'll add it as an answer for better visibility. Please give me your feedback on the PubSub when you try it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `$rootScope.$broadcast` could be performance greedy depending on the size of your app.  (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs) for more info.)

If you want to communicate between controllers on sibling nodes, there are 2 ways:

- use a common parent controller
- use a shared service.

With my team, we decided to develop a small pub/sub service to solve a similar issue. If you want to try it, here's our [angular-pubsub service](https://github.com/glepretre/angular-pubsub).

Comment: You were completely correct about $broadcast being the wrong way to go. I use a service now as you suggest. +1 for that. The problem was something different but you were right as well.