# AngularJS Decorator without object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polyfills, es5-shim, angular-decorator

How do I use decorators without having access to object.defineProperty?

I am looking into the shims available:

- [es5-sham](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-sham.js)
- [polyfill](https://github.com/cujojs/poly/blob/master/object.js)

but in case those don't pass testing, is there another way decorators were intended to work?

I am using the decorator for [$onRootScope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19498009/863924).

I am using angular 1.08. I need compatibility with IE7.

**Update**

I have tried out a few methods that seem to work but I don't know the difference between them: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDC4PPAfFDtX7WFUjgOW?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.config(['$provide', function($provide){
  $provide.decorator('$rootScope', ['$delegate', function($delegate){
    $delegate.a = 1;
    $delegate.constructor.prototype.b = 2;
    Object.defineProperty($delegate.constructor.prototype, 'c', {
      value: 3
    });
    return $delegate;
  }]);
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  console.log($rootScope);   //reveals `a` property
  console.log($rootScope.constructor.prototype); //=> {b:2, c:3}
  console.log($rootScope.a); //=> 1
  console.log($rootScope.b); //=> 2
  console.log($rootScope.c); //=> 3
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Thank You.

Comment: Can yo give an example on why do you think you are forced to use Object.defineProperty to create a decorator over $onRootScope?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo It's in the question already. I referred to an answer on how to define $onRootScope and it uses `object.defineProperty()`. Other examples I have found also use that. Do you have an example that does *not* use `object.defineProperty()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, an equivalent solution to the pice of code you shared is:

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf($delegate));
proto['$onRootScope'] = function (name, listener) {
   var unsubscribe = $delegate.$on(name, listener);
   this.$on('$destroy', unsubscribe);
};
```

In the original code this line `$delegate.constructor.prototype` is getting access to the $delegate's prototype prototype.

Then, once you get access to it, you can simply define a new function in it. You do not need to use `defineProperty`. The only caveat is that by using `defineProperty` you can configure that the method is not enumerable (should not appear in for-each loops). In this other way, the method added would appear in for-each loops. It may not be a problem for you though.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edalorzo/qLuV6/30/) for this.

You can use [John Resig's polyfill](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/) for `getObjectPrototypeOf`if the function is not available for your current browser:

> ```
> if ( typeof Object.getPrototypeOf !== "function" ) {
>   if ( typeof "test".__proto__ === "object" ) {
>     Object.getPrototypeOf = function(object){
>       return object.__proto__;
>     };
>   } else {
>     Object.getPrototypeOf = function(object){
>       // May break if the constructor has been tampered with
>       return object.constructor.prototype;
>     };
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this suffers from the same [compatibility issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) as `object.defineProperty`. But it is interesting that you just used simple function assignment to provide the `$onRootScope` method. To get the prototype, could I just do `$delegate.prototype.prototype` or `$delegate.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype` or something?

Comment: Or can I just do `$delgate.constructor.prototype = { value: ... }`?

Comment: @ogc-nick You could use a [John Resig's polyfill](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/) for the implementation of `getPrototypeOf`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I think you slightly misunderstood my question but answered it anyways by assigning a function to `proto['$onRootScope']`.