# AngularJS Decorators IE7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-decorator

Related question: [AngularJS Decorator without object.defineProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22080588/863924)

It seems the standard way to apply decorators is with `object.defineProperty` but that is [not supported in IE7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

There are some polyfill options for `object.defineProperty`:

- [es5-sham](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-sham.js)
- [polyfill](https://github.com/cujojs/poly/blob/master/object.js)

I have also done some experimenting in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDC4PPAfFDtX7WFUjgOW?p=preview) with some interesting results.

```
<div  ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl"></div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="SiblingCtrl"></div>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.config(['$provide', function($provide){
  $provide.decorator('$rootScope', ['$delegate', function($delegate){
    $delegate.a = 1;
    $delegate.constructor.prototype.b = 2;
    Object.defineProperty($delegate.constructor.prototype, 'c', {
      value: 3
    });
    return $delegate;
  }]);
}]);

app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  console.info('ParentCtrl', $rootScope.a); // 1
  console.info('ParentCtrl', $rootScope.b); // 2
  console.info('ParentCtrl', $rootScope.c); // 3
  console.info('ParentCtrl', $rootScope.constructor.prototype.a); // undefined
  console.info('ParentCtrl', $rootScope.constructor.prototype.b); // 2
  console.info('ParentCtrl', $rootScope.constructor.prototype.c); // 3
  $rootScope.a = 'a';
  $rootScope.b = 'b';
  $rootScope.c = 'c';
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  console.info('ChildCtrl', $rootScope.a); // 1
  console.info('ChildCtrl', $rootScope.b); // b
  console.info('ChildCtrl', $rootScope.c); // 3
  console.info('ChildCtrl', $rootScope.constructor.prototype.a); // undefined
  console.info('ChildCtrl', $rootScope.constructor.prototype.b); // 2
  console.info('ChildCtrl', $rootScope.constructor.prototype.c); // 3
});

app.controller('SiblingCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  console.info('SiblingCtrl', $rootScope.a); // a
  console.info('SiblingCtrl', $rootScope.b); // b
  console.info('SiblingCtrl', $rootScope.c); // 3
  console.info('SiblingCtrl', $rootScope.constructor.prototype.a); // undefined
  console.info('SiblingCtrl', $rootScope.constructor.prototype.b); // 2
  console.info('SiblingCtrl', $rootScope.constructor.prototype.c); // 3
});
```

And my question is: Which is the right way to provide a method to rootScope like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19498009/863924) shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this

```
app.config(['$provide', function($provide){
  $provide.decorator('$rootScope', ['$delegate', function($delegate){
    $delegate.func = function() {
       ...
    };
    return $delegate;
  }]);
}]);
```

This was the simplest solution and it works in IE7. Calls to `constructor` or `prototype` or `__proto__` without or without polyfills just led to endless trouble.