# Angular js communication between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following angularjs html app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="StudentProgram">
    <head>
        <title>Student Program Management</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/badge.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{subcategory.name2}} - Add Courses</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="panel col-md-5">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p><font size="2">Required Credits : <span class="badge badge-machb pull-right">{{subcategory.required2}} </span></p>
                                <p>Completed Credits : <span class="badge badge-machb pull-right">{{subcategory.completed2}} </span></p>
                                <p>Planned Credits : <span class="badge badge-machb pull-right">{{subcategory.planned2}} </span></font></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--<input type="checkbox">{{child}}-->
                        <div class="panel progress col-md-7" style="height:121px;">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                PROGRESS
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="53.3" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 53.3%;">
                                        53.3% 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel panel-default" style="float:left;width:525px;">
                            <div class="panel-body" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example" data-offset="0" style="height:200px;overflow:auto;position:relative;">
                                <table class="table table-hover checkbox">
                                    <tr>    
                                        <th>Course</th>     
                                        <th>Credits</th>  
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr ng-repeat="child in subcategory.children">
                                        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>{{child}}</td>
                                        <td class="vcenter">3</td> 
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok()">Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">


        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-10">
            <div class="" id="content">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </div>
                <br/><br/> 
                <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
                    <div ng-repeat="detail in details">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="badge badge-machb pull-right">{{detail.completed}} / {{detail.required}}</span>{{detail.name1}}</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-repeat="subcategory in detail.subcategory1" class="panel-body">

                                <h4><strong>{{subcategory.name2}}
                                    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-disabled="subcategory.required2 == subcategory.completed2" ng-click="open(subcategory)">Add Course <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>


                                </strong></h4>
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <tr>
                                      <th>Course</th>
                                      <th>Term</th>     
                                      <th>Credit</th>
                                      <th>Grade</th>

                                    </tr>

                                    <tr ng-repeat="subcategory2 in subcategory.subcategory2">
                                      <td>{{subcategory2.course}}</td>
                                      <td>{{subcategory2.term}}</td>        
                                      <td>{{subcategory2.credit}}</td>
                                      <td>{{subcategory2.grade}}</td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>  
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = angular.module('StudentProgram', ['ui.bootstrap']);

        app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $modal, $log){
            $scope.details=[
                {name1:"TIER 1 - CORE FOUNDATIONS", completed:"9", required:"13", subcategory1:[
                    {name2:"Critical Reading and Writing",completed2:"6",required2:"6",planned2:"0",children:['ENGL-1301','HIST-1301'], subcategory2:[
                        {course:"HIST 1301",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"3.0",grade:"B"},
                        {course:"ENGL 1301",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"3.0",grade:"A"}
                    ]},
                    {name2:"Speaking and Listening",completed2:"3",required2:"3",planned2:"0",children:['SPCH-1311','SPCH-1315','SPCH-1321','ARAB-1311','ARAB-1312','ARAB-1411','ARAB-1412','CHIN-1311','CHIN-1312','CHIN-1411','CHIN-1412','CZEC-1311','CZEC-1312','CZEC-1411','CZEC-1412','FREN-1311','FREN-1312','FREN-1411','FREN-1412','GERM-1311','GERM-1312','GERM-1411','GERM-1412','GREE-1311','GREE-1312','GREE-1411','GREE-1412','ITAL-1311','ITAL-1312','ITAL-1411','ITAL-1412','JAPN-1311','JAPN-1312','JAPN-1411','JAPN-1412','KORE-1311','KORE-1312','KORE-1411','KORE-1412','LATI-1311','LATI-1312','LATI-1411','LATI-1412','PORT-1311','PORT-1312','PORT-1411','PORT-1412','RUSS-1311','RUSS-1312','RUSS-1411','RUSS-1412','SGNL-1301','SGNL-1302','SPAN-1311','SPAN-1312','SPAN-1411','SPAN-1412','VIET-1311','VIET-1312','VIET-1411','VIET-1412'], 
                    subcategory2:[
                        {course:"SPCH 1311",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"4.0",grade:"A"}
                    ]},
                    {name2:"Quantitative Reasoning",completed2:"0",required2:"4",planned2:"0",children:['MATH-1314','MATH-1414','MATH-1316','MATH-1324','MATH-1325','MATH-1425','MATH-1332','MATH-1333','MATH-1348','MATH-1350','MATH-1351','MATH-2321','MATH-2421','MATH-2342','MATH-2442','MATH-2412','MATH-2413','MATH-2414','MATH-2415','MATH-2318','MATH-2418','MATH-2320','MATH-2420','MATH-2305'], 
                    subcategory2:[

                    ]},
                    {name2:"Wellness and The Human Experience",completed2:"0",required2:"3",planned2:"0",children:['ARTS-1311','ARTS-1312','ARTS-1313','ARTS-1316','ARTS-2313','ARTS-2316','ARTS-2326','ARTS-2333','ARTS-2336','ARTS-2341','ARTS-2346','ARTS-2348','ARTS-2356','ARTS-2366','BIOL-1322','BUSI-1307','COMM-1316','COMM-1318','DANC-1245','DANC-1341','DANC-1347','DANC-1351','DRAM-1322','DRAM-1330','DRAM-1351','MUEN-1122','MUEN-1131','MUEN-1132','MUEN-1133','MUEN-1134','MUEN-1135','MUEN-1136','MUEN-1137','MUEN-1151','MUEN-1152','MUEN-1153','MUEN-2123','MUEN-2141','MUSI-1116','MUSI-1181','MUSI-1183','MUSI-1192','MUSI-1263','MUSI-1301','PHED-1100','PHED-1101','PHED-1102','PHED-1104','PHED-1105','PHED-1106','PHED-1107','PHED-1108','PHED-1109','PHED-1110','PHED-1111','PHED-1112','PHED-1113','PHED-1114','PHED-1115','PHED-1116','PHED-1117','PHED-1118','PHED-1119','PHED-1120','PHED-1121','PHED-1122','PHED-1123','PHED-1124','PHED-1125','PHED-1126','PHED-1127','PHED-1128','PHED-1129','PHED-1164','PHED-1165','PHED-1251','PHED-1304','PHED-1306','PHED-1346','SOCI-2301','SOCI-2340','SPCH 2341'], 
                    subcategory2:[

                    ]}

                ]},
                {name1:"TIER 2 - CORE DOMAINS", completed:"10", required:"26", subcategory1:[
                    {name2:"Qualitative Reasoning, Literacy and Research",completed2:"3",required2:"3",planned2:"0",children:['ENGL-1302'], 
                    subcategory2:[
                        {course:"ENGL 1302",term:"Summer 2012",credit:"3.0",grade:"A"}
                    ]},
                    {name2:"Self and Society",completed2:"3",required2:"9",planned2:"0",children:['HIST-1302','HIST-2301','HIST-2328','HIST-2381','GOVT-2305','ANTH-2302','ANTH-2346','ANTH-2351','COMM-1307','CRIJ-1301','CRIJ-1307','ECON-1301','ECON-1301','ECON-2302','ECON-2311','GEOG-1302','GEOG-1303','GEOG-2312','GOVT-2304','GOVT-2311','HIST-2321','HIST-2322','HIST-2327','PSYC-2301','PSYC-2306','PSYC-2314','PSYC-2316','SOCI-1301','SOCI-1306','SOCI-2306','SOCI-2319','SOCI-2336','TECA-1303','TECA-1354'], 
                    subcategory2:[
                        {course:"GOVT 2301",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"3.0",grade:"B"},
                        {course:"PSYC 2301",term:"Summer 2012",credit:"--",grade:"--"}
                    ]},
                    {name2:"Humanity, Creativity and the Aesthetic Experience",completed2:"0",required2:"6",planned2:"0",children:['ARTS-1301','ARTS-1303','ARTS-1304','DANC-2303','DRAM-1310','DRAM-2361','DRAM-2366','HUMA-1311','HUMA-1315','MUSI-1306','MUSI-1308','MUSI-1309','MUSI-1310',
                                                                                         'CUST-2370','ENGL-2321','ENGL-2322','ENGL-2323','ENGL-2326','ENGL-2327','ENGL-2328','ENGL-2331','ENGL-2332','ENGL-2333','ENGL-2342','ENGL-2343','ENGL-2351','HUMA-1302','HUMA-1305','HUMA-2319','PHIL-1301','PHIL-1304','PHIL-1316','PHIL-1317','PHIL-2303','PHIL-2306','PHIL-2307','PHIL-2316','PHIL-2317','PHIL-2318','PHIL-2321','ARAB-2311','ARAB-2312','CHIN-2311','CHIN-2312','CZEC-2311','CZEC-2312','FREN-2311','FREN-2312','GERM-2311','GERM-2312','GREE-2311','GREE-2312','ITAL-2311','ITAL-2312','JAPN-2311','JAPN-2312','KORE-2311','KORE-2312','LATI-2311','LATI-2312','PORT-2311','PORT-2312','RUSS-2311','RUSS-2312','SPAN-2311','PAN-2312','SPAN-2321','SPAN-2322','SPAN-2323','SPAN-2324','VIET-2311','VIET-2312'], 
                    subcategory2:[

                    ]},
                    {name2:"Scientific Discovery and Sustainability",completed2:"4",required2:"8",planned2:"0",children:['ANTH-2401','BIOL-1406','BIOL-1407','BIOL-1408','BIOL-1409','BIOL-1411','BIOL-2401','BIOL-2402','BIOL-2406','BIOL-2416','BIOL-2420','BIOL-2421','CHEM-1405','CHEM-1406','CHEM-1407','CHEM-1411','CHEM-1412','CHEM-2423','CHEM-2425','ENVR-1401','ENVR-1402','GEOL-1401','GEOL-1402','GEOL-1403','GEOL-1404','GEOL-1405','GEOL-1445','GEOL-1447','PHYS-1401','PHYS-1402','PHYS-1403','PHYS-1404','PHYS-1405','PHYS-1407','PHYS-1415','PHYS-1417','PHYS-2425','PHYS-2426'], 
                          subcategory2:[
                        {course:"BIOL 1406",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"4.0",grade:"B"},
                        {course:"BIOL 1407",term:"Summer 2012",credit:"--",grade:"--"}
                    ]}
                ]}

            ];
            $scope.open = function (subcat) {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
                    resolve: {
                        detail: function() {
                            return subcat;
                        }
                    }   
                });
            };

        });

        var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, detail) {
            $scope.subcategory = detail;

            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
            };

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        };



    </script>


    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works great with the way the controller is designed currently.

But i would like to know if we can make it work the same way using the following controllers with the parameters name, completed, required, planned to be in sync in both the controllers and fetch data from both the controllers simultaneously.

```
var app = angular.module('StudentProgram', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $modal, $log){
    $scope.details=[
        {name1:"TIER 1 - CORE FOUNDATIONS", completed:"9", required:"13", subcategory1:[
            {name2:"Critical Reading and Writing",completed2:"6",required2:"6",planned2:"0",children:['ENGL-1301','HIST-1301'], subcategory2:[
                {course:"HIST 1301",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"3.0",grade:"B"},
                {course:"ENGL 1301",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"3.0",grade:"A"}
            ]},
            {name2:"Speaking and Listening",completed2:"3",required2:"3",planned2:"0",children:['SPCH-1311','SPCH-1315','SPCH-1321','ARAB-1311','ARAB-1312','ARAB-1411','ARAB-1412','CHIN-1311','CHIN-1312','CHIN-1411','CHIN-1412','CZEC-1311','CZEC-1312','CZEC-1411','CZEC-1412','FREN-1311','FREN-1312','FREN-1411','FREN-1412','GERM-1311','GERM-1312','GERM-1411','GERM-1412','GREE-1311','GREE-1312','GREE-1411','GREE-1412','ITAL-1311','ITAL-1312','ITAL-1411','ITAL-1412','JAPN-1311','JAPN-1312','JAPN-1411','JAPN-1412','KORE-1311','KORE-1312','KORE-1411','KORE-1412','LATI-1311','LATI-1312','LATI-1411','LATI-1412','PORT-1311','PORT-1312','PORT-1411','PORT-1412','RUSS-1311','RUSS-1312','RUSS-1411','RUSS-1412','SGNL-1301','SGNL-1302','SPAN-1311','SPAN-1312','SPAN-1411','SPAN-1412','VIET-1311','VIET-1312','VIET-1411','VIET-1412'], 
            subcategory2:[
                {course:"SPCH 1311",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"4.0",grade:"A"}
            ]},
            {name2:"Quantitative Reasoning",completed2:"0",required2:"4",planned2:"0",children:['MATH-1314','MATH-1414','MATH-1316','MATH-1324','MATH-1325','MATH-1425','MATH-1332','MATH-1333','MATH-1348','MATH-1350','MATH-1351','MATH-2321','MATH-2421','MATH-2342','MATH-2442','MATH-2412','MATH-2413','MATH-2414','MATH-2415','MATH-2318','MATH-2418','MATH-2320','MATH-2420','MATH-2305'], 
            subcategory2:[

            ]},
            {name2:"Wellness and The Human Experience",completed2:"0",required2:"3",planned2:"0",children:['ARTS-1311','ARTS-1312','ARTS-1313','ARTS-1316','ARTS-2313','ARTS-2316','ARTS-2326','ARTS-2333','ARTS-2336','ARTS-2341','ARTS-2346','ARTS-2348','ARTS-2356','ARTS-2366','BIOL-1322','BUSI-1307','COMM-1316','COMM-1318','DANC-1245','DANC-1341','DANC-1347','DANC-1351','DRAM-1322','DRAM-1330','DRAM-1351','MUEN-1122','MUEN-1131','MUEN-1132','MUEN-1133','MUEN-1134','MUEN-1135','MUEN-1136','MUEN-1137','MUEN-1151','MUEN-1152','MUEN-1153','MUEN-2123','MUEN-2141','MUSI-1116','MUSI-1181','MUSI-1183','MUSI-1192','MUSI-1263','MUSI-1301','PHED-1100','PHED-1101','PHED-1102','PHED-1104','PHED-1105','PHED-1106','PHED-1107','PHED-1108','PHED-1109','PHED-1110','PHED-1111','PHED-1112','PHED-1113','PHED-1114','PHED-1115','PHED-1116','PHED-1117','PHED-1118','PHED-1119','PHED-1120','PHED-1121','PHED-1122','PHED-1123','PHED-1124','PHED-1125','PHED-1126','PHED-1127','PHED-1128','PHED-1129','PHED-1164','PHED-1165','PHED-1251','PHED-1304','PHED-1306','PHED-1346','SOCI-2301','SOCI-2340','SPCH 2341'], 
            subcategory2:[

            ]}

        ]},
        {name1:"TIER 2 - CORE DOMAINS", completed:"10", required:"26", subcategory1:[
            {name2:"Qualitative Reasoning, Literacy and Research",completed2:"3",required2:"3",planned2:"0",children:['ENGL-1302'], 
            subcategory2:[
                {course:"ENGL 1302",term:"Summer 2012",credit:"3.0",grade:"A"}
            ]},
            {name2:"Self and Society",completed2:"3",required2:"9",planned2:"0",children:['HIST-1302','HIST-2301','HIST-2328','HIST-2381','GOVT-2305','ANTH-2302','ANTH-2346','ANTH-2351','COMM-1307','CRIJ-1301','CRIJ-1307','ECON-1301','ECON-1301','ECON-2302','ECON-2311','GEOG-1302','GEOG-1303','GEOG-2312','GOVT-2304','GOVT-2311','HIST-2321','HIST-2322','HIST-2327','PSYC-2301','PSYC-2306','PSYC-2314','PSYC-2316','SOCI-1301','SOCI-1306','SOCI-2306','SOCI-2319','SOCI-2336','TECA-1303','TECA-1354'], 
            subcategory2:[
                {course:"GOVT 2301",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"3.0",grade:"B"},
                {course:"PSYC 2301",term:"Summer 2012",credit:"--",grade:"--"}
            ]},
            {name2:"Humanity, Creativity and the Aesthetic Experience",completed2:"0",required2:"6",planned2:"0",children:['ARTS-1301','ARTS-1303','ARTS-1304','DANC-2303','DRAM-1310','DRAM-2361','DRAM-2366','HUMA-1311','HUMA-1315','MUSI-1306','MUSI-1308','MUSI-1309','MUSI-1310',
                                                                                 'CUST-2370','ENGL-2321','ENGL-2322','ENGL-2323','ENGL-2326','ENGL-2327','ENGL-2328','ENGL-2331','ENGL-2332','ENGL-2333','ENGL-2342','ENGL-2343','ENGL-2351','HUMA-1302','HUMA-1305','HUMA-2319','PHIL-1301','PHIL-1304','PHIL-1316','PHIL-1317','PHIL-2303','PHIL-2306','PHIL-2307','PHIL-2316','PHIL-2317','PHIL-2318','PHIL-2321','ARAB-2311','ARAB-2312','CHIN-2311','CHIN-2312','CZEC-2311','CZEC-2312','FREN-2311','FREN-2312','GERM-2311','GERM-2312','GREE-2311','GREE-2312','ITAL-2311','ITAL-2312','JAPN-2311','JAPN-2312','KORE-2311','KORE-2312','LATI-2311','LATI-2312','PORT-2311','PORT-2312','RUSS-2311','RUSS-2312','SPAN-2311','PAN-2312','SPAN-2321','SPAN-2322','SPAN-2323','SPAN-2324','VIET-2311','VIET-2312'], 
            subcategory2:[

            ]},
            {name2:"Scientific Discovery and Sustainability",completed2:"4",required2:"8",planned2:"0",children:['ANTH-2401','BIOL-1406','BIOL-1407','BIOL-1408','BIOL-1409','BIOL-1411','BIOL-2401','BIOL-2402','BIOL-2406','BIOL-2416','BIOL-2420','BIOL-2421','CHEM-1405','CHEM-1406','CHEM-1407','CHEM-1411','CHEM-1412','CHEM-2423','CHEM-2425','ENVR-1401','ENVR-1402','GEOL-1401','GEOL-1402','GEOL-1403','GEOL-1404','GEOL-1405','GEOL-1445','GEOL-1447','PHYS-1401','PHYS-1402','PHYS-1403','PHYS-1404','PHYS-1405','PHYS-1407','PHYS-1415','PHYS-1417','PHYS-2425','PHYS-2426'], 
                  subcategory2:[
                {course:"BIOL 1406",term:"Spring 2012",credit:"4.0",grade:"B"},
                {course:"BIOL 1407",term:"Summer 2012",credit:"--",grade:"--"}
            ]}
        ]}

    ];
    $scope.open = function (subcat) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                detail: function() {
                    return subcat;
                }
            }   
        });
    };

});

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, detail) {
    $scope.subcategory = detail;

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};

app.controller('mydata', function($scope){
    $scope.details=[
        {name1:"TIER 1 - CORE FOUNDATIONS", completed:"9", required:"13", subcategory1:[
            {name2:"Critical Reading and Writing",completed2:"6",required2:"6",planned2:"0",
            children:['ENGL-1301','HIST-1301'],
            },
            {name2:"Speaking and Listening",completed2:"3",required2:"3",planned2:"0",
            children:['SPCH-1311','SPCH-1315','SPCH-1321','ARAB-1311','ARAB-1312','ARAB-1411','ARAB-1412','CHIN-1311','CHIN-1312','CHIN-1411','CHIN-1412','CZEC-1311','CZEC-1312','CZEC-1411','CZEC-1412','FREN-1311','FREN-1312','FREN-1411','FREN-1412','GERM-1311','GERM-1312','GERM-1411','GERM-1412','GREE-1311','GREE-1312','GREE-1411','GREE-1412','ITAL-1311','ITAL-1312','ITAL-1411','ITAL-1412','JAPN-1311','JAPN-1312','JAPN-1411','JAPN-1412','KORE-1311','KORE-1312','KORE-1411','KORE-1412','LATI-1311','LATI-1312','LATI-1411','LATI-1412','PORT-1311','PORT-1312','PORT-1411','PORT-1412','RUSS-1311','RUSS-1312','RUSS-1411','RUSS-1412','SGNL-1301','SGNL-1302','SPAN-1311','SPAN-1312','SPAN-1411','SPAN-1412','VIET-1311','VIET-1312','VIET-1411','VIET-1412']
            },
            {name2:"Quantitative Reasoning",completed2:"0",required2:"4",planned2:"0",
            children:['MATH-1314','MATH-1414','MATH-1316','MATH-1324','MATH-1325','MATH-1425','MATH-1332','MATH-1333','MATH-1348','MATH-1350','MATH-1351','MATH-2321','MATH-2421','MATH-2342','MATH-2442','MATH-2412','MATH-2413','MATH-2414','MATH-2415','MATH-2318','MATH-2418','MATH-2320','MATH-2420','MATH-2305']
            ]},
            {name2:"Wellness and The Human Experience",completed2:"0",required2:"3",planned2:"0",
            children:['ARTS-1311','ARTS-1312','ARTS-1313','ARTS-1316','ARTS-2313','ARTS-2316','ARTS-2326','ARTS-2333','ARTS-2336','ARTS-2341','ARTS-2346','ARTS-2348','ARTS-2356','ARTS-2366','BIOL-1322','BUSI-1307','COMM-1316','COMM-1318','DANC-1245','DANC-1341','DANC-1347','DANC-1351','DRAM-1322','DRAM-1330','DRAM-1351','MUEN-1122','MUEN-1131','MUEN-1132','MUEN-1133','MUEN-1134','MUEN-1135','MUEN-1136','MUEN-1137','MUEN-1151','MUEN-1152','MUEN-1153','MUEN-2123','MUEN-2141','MUSI-1116','MUSI-1181','MUSI-1183','MUSI-1192','MUSI-1263','MUSI-1301','PHED-1100','PHED-1101','PHED-1102','PHED-1104','PHED-1105','PHED-1106','PHED-1107','PHED-1108','PHED-1109','PHED-1110','PHED-1111','PHED-1112','PHED-1113','PHED-1114','PHED-1115','PHED-1116','PHED-1117','PHED-1118','PHED-1119','PHED-1120','PHED-1121','PHED-1122','PHED-1123','PHED-1124','PHED-1125','PHED-1126','PHED-1127','PHED-1128','PHED-1129','PHED-1164','PHED-1165','PHED-1251','PHED-1304','PHED-1306','PHED-1346','SOCI-2301','SOCI-2340','SPCH 2341']
            }

        ]},
        {name1:"TIER 2 - CORE DOMAINS", completed:"10", required:"26", subcategory1:[
            {name2:"Qualitative Reasoning, Literacy and Research",completed2:"3",required2:"3",planned2:"0",
            children:['ENGL-1302']
            },
            {name2:"Self and Society",completed2:"3",required2:"9",planned2:"0",
            children:['HIST-1302','HIST-2301','HIST-2328','HIST-2381','GOVT-2305','ANTH-2302','ANTH-2346','ANTH-2351','COMM-1307','CRIJ-1301','CRIJ-1307','ECON-1301','ECON-1301','ECON-2302','ECON-2311','GEOG-1302','GEOG-1303','GEOG-2312','GOVT-2304','GOVT-2311','HIST-2321','HIST-2322','HIST-2327','PSYC-2301','PSYC-2306','PSYC-2314','PSYC-2316','SOCI-1301','SOCI-1306','SOCI-2306','SOCI-2319','SOCI-2336','TECA-1303','TECA-1354'] 
            },
            {name2:"Humanity, Creativity and the Aesthetic Experience",completed2:"0",required2:"6",planned2:"0",children:['ARTS-1301','ARTS-1303','ARTS-1304','DANC-2303','DRAM-1310','DRAM-2361','DRAM-2366','HUMA-1311','HUMA-1315','MUSI-1306','MUSI-1308','MUSI-1309','MUSI-1310',
                                                                                 'CUST-2370','ENGL-2321','ENGL-2322','ENGL-2323','ENGL-2326','ENGL-2327','ENGL-2328','ENGL-2331','ENGL-2332','ENGL-2333','ENGL-2342','ENGL-2343','ENGL-2351','HUMA-1302','HUMA-1305','HUMA-2319','PHIL-1301','PHIL-1304','PHIL-1316','PHIL-1317','PHIL-2303','PHIL-2306','PHIL-2307','PHIL-2316','PHIL-2317','PHIL-2318','PHIL-2321','ARAB-2311','ARAB-2312','CHIN-2311','CHIN-2312','CZEC-2311','CZEC-2312','FREN-2311','FREN-2312','GERM-2311','GERM-2312','GREE-2311','GREE-2312','ITAL-2311','ITAL-2312','JAPN-2311','JAPN-2312','KORE-2311','KORE-2312','LATI-2311','LATI-2312','PORT-2311','PORT-2312','RUSS-2311','RUSS-2312','SPAN-2311','PAN-2312','SPAN-2321','SPAN-2322','SPAN-2323','SPAN-2324','VIET-2311','VIET-2312']
            },
            {name2:"Scientific Discovery and Sustainability",completed2:"4",required2:"8",planned2:"0",
            children:['ANTH-2401','BIOL-1406','BIOL-1407','BIOL-1408','BIOL-1409','BIOL-1411','BIOL-2401','BIOL-2402','BIOL-2406','BIOL-2416','BIOL-2420','BIOL-2421','CHEM-1405','CHEM-1406','CHEM-1407','CHEM-1411','CHEM-1412','CHEM-2423','CHEM-2425','ENVR-1401','ENVR-1402','GEOL-1401','GEOL-1402','GEOL-1403','GEOL-1404','GEOL-1405','GEOL-1445','GEOL-1447','PHYS-1401','PHYS-1402','PHYS-1403','PHYS-1404','PHYS-1405','PHYS-1407','PHYS-1415','PHYS-1417','PHYS-2425','PHYS-2426']
            }
        ]}

    ];
});
```

So the question is whether we can call data from both the controllers simultaneously and make sure that the common data in both the controllers stay in sync such that the functionality of the app does not change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Comment: Am not really sure if that post you mentioned answers my question. But thanks for the link

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what factories were made for.

```
app.factory('myFactory', function() {
    return {
      // The data you want to keep in sync
    };
});
```

Then add it as a dependency:

```
app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $modal, $log, myFactory){
    $scope.myData = myFactory;
```

[Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe)

Comment: Could you tell me how exactly i will include the data in the controllers after i define the data in the factory such that they fit into the substructures of the controller?

Comment: @AbhishekReddy Here, I'm adding it to `$scope` as the `myData` property, but you can use `myFactory` however you want.