# How can a service $watch another service's data?

Tags: angularjs

I have two services which fetch two different kinds of data from my server. Each of those has two controllers which `$scope.$watch` that data for changes.

I wanted to get smart and detect loss/re-gain of internet connection, so I added an `app.service('internetConnectionAvailableService'`. When one of my data fetch services detects an HTTP result, it informs the "internetConnectionAvailableService" of success or failure.

I would like the other data fetch service to be aware of that.

I suppose that I could just lump both data fetch service into one & drop the internetConnectionAvailableService, but I would rather not (what if I end up with more data fetch services?).

So, I figure it's either `broadcast` / `$on` or use a `$watch`. Google seems to recommend using a `$watch`, but I can't seem to get it work in my data fetch service ....

```
app.service('GetServerDataService',function(){
   var serverData;
  return {
           getServerData: function()
            {
                return serverData;
            },

           $scope.$watch(internetConnectionAvailableService.isInternetConnectionAvailable,   
              function(){
         }
    }
 }
```

gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . "

I am very new to Angular, so had a wild guess at using `$rootscope.$watch` instead, but that gives me the same message.

What am I doing wrong? How to I watch another service's data? Or should I use `broadcast` instead?

### Update

I think I could have phrased this better and asked "How do communicate between two services?"

Comment: Your example does not seem to be valid JavaScript. Can you fix it, pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

It seems you want to communicate between services. You can indeed use $rootScope broadcast, which will trigger a broadcast storm along all your controllers and watches. A more object-oriented approach is to create a PubSub service which your services can inject and use. See also this question:

[What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Comment: It's totally legit to add a `$rootscope.$watch` in a global component like a service/provider/decorator etc.

Comment: Ignoring this specific case, I've seen several well-written Angular applications that use $watch in services. Even AngularJS tech lead's demo app is using some: https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme There are times where it is the best approach, so I wouldn't say 'Watches should be done in controllers, not in services.' is some golden rule.

Comment: And how often has those watches been on $rootScope, and how often on other scope? Of course, you can use $rootScope as kind of a queue/broadcast beacon thingy, but in general it is terrible. You can do it much more elegantly.

Comment: Sorry for begin such a n00b ;-)  The key point, I think is that I want to communicate between services

Comment: @Mawg if you want to communicate between services, you can use $rootScope to do broadcast, or you can use a more elegant approach. check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs