# $rootscope.$on increases count on subscribers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular controller, a fairly simple one:

```
angular.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootscope.$on('channel.message', function () {
      // do stuff here
    }
});
```

I have some sidebar on my page, which navigates me to a view attached to controller as above.

The issue is that each time I click on a link, Angular instantiates the controller - that's totally fine, but I can see that the count of subscribers for my `'channel.message'` is growing, which is not what I want.

I understand that, well, code just adds another callback to queue, but I'm looking to avoid that issue. I want only a single subscriber. What are best practices here?

BTW: I know about **$scope**.$on. It doesn't count because of performance implications and architecture design of the app itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try calling your event handler in a named function, which will call it and clean it up. Something like this (also, make sure `$rootscope` is **`$rootScope`**):

```
angular.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    var cleanUp = $rootScope.$on('channel.message', function () {
        // do stuff here
    };

    cleanUp();
});
```

I was having your same issue (with multiple callbacks being added to the queue), and the above solution worked for me.

---

Also, this is off topic, but I might suggest formatting your controller as follows (just a recommendation):

```
angular.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really brilliant, I was not aware of it. With regards to code formatting, I'm totally fine with that, I've cook up sample code in a min so...anyway, nice to re-instantiate it in memory :)

Answer (score 2):

As @JoshBeam pointed out the return value of $rootScope.$on() is a function that will deregister your listener.  As he pointed out:

```
var cleanUp = $rootscope.$on('channel.message', function () {
   // do stuff here
}
```

The remaining question is when to trigger the cleanup.  You most likely only want to deregister when the controller is destroyed.  Happily just before Angular tears down a scope (due, for instance, to the controller being destroyed) it fires a [`$destroy` event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) on that particular scope.  So you can use the following to trigger a cleanup.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  cleanUp();
};
```

Note that, just for tear down purposes, we're listening for a `$destroy` on `$scope` (not `$rootScope`) so we get the message when the controller is torn down.  You can leave your regular listener attached to `$rootScope`.

Also note that this is also a good pattern to use to prevent memory leaks- even if you're not worried about multiple listeners.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to create an `$onRootScope` method as described in my answer here:

[What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs/19498009#19498009)

This automatically abstracts away the deregistration of the event handler and the usage is as simple as `$scope.$onRootScope('fooEvent', function(){})`

Also please note that the performance implications of broadcasted events became less of an issue with recent versions of angular.

Comment: Thanks, it's already more like coding stuff, rather then general idea. but I'm happy to count it. Great link!