# Require a Directive's Controller inside another Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get two directives to communicate with each other via their (inner defined) controllers, but I'm new to angular and still not clear on a couple of things.

Essentially, I just want two separate directives where, when you click on an element inside directive *A*, some function within *B* executes; I want to tell *B* to update itself, based on what happens in *A*. What I've got so far:

```
app.directive('A', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        require:'B',
        templateUrl:'a.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, bController){
            //should I run B's behavior here?
            //how? can't reach B's controller
        },
        controller: function(){
            //or here?
            //how do I access B's controller here?
        },
        controllerAs:'A'
    };
});

app.directive('B', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'b.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){

        },
        controller: function(){
            //here there'll be functions that manipulate
            //elements inside this directive (B)
        },
        controllerAs:'B'
    };
});
```

I'm getting an error, since *A* is trying to find the **controller** named *B*, but it's a directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq

Also, should I manipulate elements from within the `link` function, or the directives controller? Even after reading, I'm still a bit fuzzy on `link` vs `controller`; the way I see it: `link` is like a constructor of sorts, whereas the controller is where behavior goes.

So does that mean I always place DOM manipulation inside of the controller?

Is there any other way to approach this? I've read a bit about `$scope`, but still not entirely clear on that either.

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication    might help you.

Comment: Actually, I've been watching them! They definitely help, but I feel as if he didn't go deep enough (at least in that video). He only talks about `link` functions, but not controllers.

Comment: I think he has done pretty good job. Okay no problem.
 look this way can't help you. come up with task or target then can help you.

Comment: are you confused with link: and controller: functions of single directive ?? OR communication of two directives?

Answer (score 3):

You can only require directives in parent elements or in the same element. You're probably using B inside A, or vice verse.

If that's the case, you have **one directive being used inside the other**, you can go to the inner direcive and require the outer by using: `require: '^A'`. The `^` means it can be directive from your parent.

If the directives **are siblings**, you could build a third directive that would parent them both, and required it from inside both and they would use this medium to communicate:

```js
app.directive('C', function() {
  return {
    controller: function() {
      this.registerPartyA = function(partyA) {
        // ...
      };

      this.registerPartyB = function(partyB) {
        // ...
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Then from your directives;

```js
app.directive('B', function() {
  return {
    require: '^C',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, cCtrl) {
      cCtrl.registerPartyB(...);

      // maybe when user clicks you do
      // cCtrl.aCtrl.doSomething()
    }
  };
});
```

If **they're not related anyhow**, you could still use a service and inject the service in both directives, and use this as a common place.

Finally, if **both directives share the same scope** (are under the same element, or none of the directives require isolated/children scopes) you could simply declare the method directly inside the `$scope` and simply call it from the other directive:

```
app.directive('A', function() {
  return {
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.declaredByA = function() {
        // ...
      };
    }
  };
});

app.directive('B', function() {
  return {
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.clicked = function() {
        $scope.declaredByA();
      };
    }
  };
});
```

And a last call, you could use [`$scope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$emit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs) to do the communication.

**I would try in the order I've mentioned**, as long as you meet the requirements.

Comment: Thanks! Gonna look into services first!

Answer (score 1):

From the AngularJS documentation for controllers:

> Use controllers to:
>
> - Set up the initial state of the $scope object.
> - Add behavior to the $scope object.
>
> Do not use controllers to:
>
> - Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic.
>     Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects
>     its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives
>     to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.
> - Format input — Use angular form controls instead. Filter output — Use angular filters instead.
> - **Share code or state across controllers — Use angular services instead.**
> - Manage the life-cycle of other components (for example, to create
>     service instances).

From the AngularJS documentation for directives:

> Directives can be thought of as markers on a  DOM element (such as an
>   attribute, element name,  comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's
>   HTML  compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior  to that DOM
>   element or even transform the DOM element  and its children.

So, just to make things clear, no you should **never** manipulate the DOM from within a controller. You should always use the directives `link` function to manipulate the DOM.

If you want your controllers to share state information with one another, you should consider adding an angular Service (documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)). Service are objects that are instantiated once, and whose state is preserve across the module. They can be injected into controllers.

Another option is to implement some `$emit` and `$on` event raisers and listeners. This would allow you to communicate across your controllers using events to signal state changes. Here is another SO post that explains this better than I could: [Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/scope-emit-and-on-angularjs).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think a service is what I'm looking for. On another note, what if I want to set up a button, that when clicked, toggles something somewhere else (another directive for example). Should that go inside a controller or link?

Comment: But how would that `var` be available to the other directive? Let's say these directives are siblings inside the body: how would toggling said `var` in directive A be available to it's sister directive B? Isn't the `var` defined within A's controller and only available to A?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted that last comment before I was finished. Here it is again: What you would want to do, is inside of a controller create a boolean variable. Then reference that inside an `ng-click` directive like this: `<div ng-click="toggleVariable = !toggleVariable">...</div>`. This will cause the boolean `toggleVariable` to be toggle true or false, depending on the current value. Then, you can use that variable elsewhere to toggle something on/off. Here is a plunker with a running example: http://plnkr.co/edit/8o3Jl9Wk2qhh1AXYyLjO?p=preview

Comment: And yes, to answer your other question it would only be available within the `$scope` of the controller it is defined within. You can get around this by creating a parent controller that encapsulates both of the controllers that are defined in your directives. You would then include an **isolate scope** in your directives, and pass the toggle variable into your isolate scope by reference `&`. This would allow you to have access to the parent scope variable in both controllers. Google the documentation for directives, and then search for isolate scope.

Comment: On another note, should I manipulate my styles/animations in the controller or the link function? Does that even count as DOM manipulation?

Comment: @yoaquim consider investigating the `ng-style` directive