# Which method exchange data between controllers better

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

Sendind data between controllers use Service. But what better?
Use `$on` at controller and `$broadcast` at service;
Or simply javascript Object? (Exp:

```
myapp.factory('MyService', function(){
    var obj = {};

    return{
        setObject: function(value){
            obj.value = value;
        },

        getObject: function(){
            return obj;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What is your actual use case?

Comment: @Sprottenwels I have search controller with can search by 3 instance. That controller has 'Search' button and tabs which choose searched instance. Another - Instance1Controller may generated view for searched list. So I may exchange data between controllers.

Comment: @Sprottenwels and global question: at what situation use each method?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can exchange data between two controllers by using same service
example:

```
myapp.controller('myController', ['$scope','MyService'
function ( $scope,myService) {
   var obj={};
   obj=myService.setObject();
   $scope.obj=obj;
}]);

myapp.controller('myController2', ['$scope','MyService'
function ( $scope,myService) {
   var obj2={};
   obj2=myService.setObject();
   $scope.obj2=obj2;
}]);

 myapp.factory('MyService', function(){
    var obj = {};

    _setObject = function (value) {
      obj.value = value;
      return obj;
    }

    _getObject = function () {
        return obj;
    }

    return {
        setObject : _setObject ,
        getObject :_getObject 
    }
});
```

controllers contains the reference of service object when one controller change the object the other controller object automatically get changed because they shared the same reference of that service object

Comment: I know that, but I asked what method more better

Comment: this is better because $broadcast and $on starts event bubbling and creats more $watches which  slows the perfomance and not easy to manage . and secondly angular also say use minimum $on and broadcast as possible for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs