# How can we make controllers interact with each other in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to access a functionality mentioned in an other controller in some other controoller. Please suggest a way tfor interactions between different controllers residing in different scopes.

Comment: You can `$broadcast` events between them from `$rootScope`

Comment: This question has been asked so many times now... what have you tried so far? Did you research the topic? Where is your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Try to share a scope or transform what you need to share to service.

If you get data from a shared source (server, localstorage) transform the function to a generic service and use this service in both controllers.

If you get a value in one controller and want to use it in another one you can $emit events on rootScope.