# How to get the param from another controller when using the 'ui-router'?

Tags: angularjs

This is the view code:

```
<a type="button" ui-sref="index.usermng.userInfo" ng-click="checkUserInfo(item.id)" class="btn btn-primary">check</a>
```

Controller:

```
//UserManage Controller
userApp.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'serverUrl', function($scope, $http, 
$scope.checkUserInfo = function(userId) {
    console.log(userId);//I can get userId in here
    $scope.$broadcast('toUserInfo',userId);
}
}]);

//UsrInfo Controller
userApp.controller('userInfoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'serverUrl', function($scope, $http, serverUrl) {

$scope.$on('toUserInfo',function(data){
    console.log("in.....");
    console.log(data);
})
```

How to get the 'userId' from 'userCtrl' in 'userInfoCtrl'?

Comment: What is `data` in the `$on`?

Comment: @tymeJV nothing in console

Comment: Show the controller relationships. Are you sure it is parent/child ? Are you sure `item.id` is defined when you broadcast?

Comment: @charlietfl updated my code,is it parent/child?

Comment: Not enough information is shown to know what the relationship is. Are you using a router? Or just declaring them the controllers in the html?

Comment: @charlietfl you are right.it's not parent/child.Then how to  communicate between controllers

Comment: @user2734679 using ui-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using rootScope to communicate between controllers

```
userApp.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 
function($scope, $http,$rootScope) { 
    $scope.checkUserInfo = function(userId) {
       console.log(userId);//I can get userId in here
       $rootScope.$broadcast('toUserInfo',userId);
    }
}]);
```

Now the `userInfoCtrl` can get the `userId` from `userCtrl`.

Comment: thanks,but I find this issue in another question:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs],the first answer