# Sharing data between controllers and waiting a return

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have two controllers and I'm using a factory to declare objects. In the main controller I call the other like this:

```
var a = $controller('otherController', {$scope: $scope});
```

In the second controller, I have a function and I want to return an array to make something in the main

```
$scope.function = function(items){

        //some data things

        return auxItems;
    };
```

The question is, in the main I call the function but I need the return to work. How can I "wait" the return in the main controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Comment: If you need to communicate between controllers, it means you should rethink your design (in 99% of cases). Keep in mind that business logic should be put into services, not in controllers

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to communicate between controllers. Use `$scope.$on` and `$rootScope.$broadcast` instead.

A much more detailed explanation can be found here:
[What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can comunicate between classes using services.
You can check this link
[link](http://www.i-avington.com/Posts/Post/angularjs-using-a-service-to-communicate-between-two-different-controllers)

But the problem is you should not need to comunicate two sibling classes.
Rethink your design