# Do something on radio button selection change AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to refresh some data depending on selection of a particular radio button group.

working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/kZhsiU4pVpHhoscVkvMQ?p=preview

But I can get neither the ng-change nor the ng-click to execute my method which updates name and makes Hello World to show Hello 'selection'.

```
$scope.updateValue = function(){
    $scope.name = $scope.data.myNumber;
  };
```

But I can see that the two way data binding works - so the model is getting updated.

```
<span>You selected {{ data.myNumber }}</span>
```

On a side note: another thing I tried is to watch the model value and execute what I want to do, but that does not work either - the watchcollection is not triggered ever again other than at page load.

The plunker is just a representation of the radio button selection problem - what I want to achieve in the data refresh is more complex.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want it to be changed on the main page while the modal is open?

Comment: Yes I want it to be changed on the main page - when a selection is made. Basically Hello World should update to Hello 'selection'! But obviously you see it only when u click on OK.

Comment: for complex data communication, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the $scope variable for name, modify object property as it keeps the reference change.

change your html part of code to this...

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <p>Hello {{data.name}}!</p>
      <button ng-click="OpenModal('sm')">Enter Number</button>
      <br><br>
      <span>You selected {{ data.myNumber }}</span>

  </div>
```

And your javascript controller to this...

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.OpenModal = function(size){
   var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'Modal.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            windowClass: 'small-size-modal',
            size: size,
            scope: $scope
        });
  };
});

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance){
  $scope.ok = function(){
    $scope.data.name = $scope.data.myNumber;
    $modalInstance.close();

  };

  $scope.updateValue = function(){
    $scope.data.name = $scope.data.myNumber;
    $modalInstance.dismiss('submit');
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Working Plunker..

http://plnkr.co/edit/xL4b6imAkvwuNiuBuHxl?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

While other answers seem valid, what I would do for complex data communication is to use a service in between.

As you have two separate controllers, one in your main page and one for the modal, and their `$scope`s are different, I'd go for using a `service` for communication between two controllers. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs) out for more information on this.

Simply broadcast the changes on your modal, then listen for those changes on your main controller and reflect it on the HTML.