# How can I pass between controllers in same module?

Tags: angularjs

In module named `EventDetails` I have two controllers `attachedFilesList` and `EventDetailsctrl`.

I need to pass string value from `EventDetailsctrl` controller to  attachedFilesList controller.

How can I pass between controllers in same module?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs

Comment: Use events. ie: **$emit** from one controller. Then listen in the other controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is attached below:

### In EventDetailsctrl

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('pass-value', 'dummyVal');
```

### In attachedFilesList

```
$scope.$on('pass-value', function(event, value) {
  // value is the object which is passed from $broadcast
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the data from one controller to another controller using `service`.

```
EventDetails
  .controller('attachedFilesList', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice',
     function($rootScope, $scope, myservice) {
         $scope.myservice = myservice;
     }
  ]);

EventDetails
  .controller('EventDetailsctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice',
     function($rootScope, $scope, myservice) {
         $scope.myservice = myservice;
     }
  ]);

EventDetails
   .service('myservice', function() {
       this.name = "value";
   });
```

Here is the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8mtG8SazkemZ42jdQRZs?p=preview)

Hope it helps :)