# how can i inject a controller in an other in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

My question is how can i inject a controller in an other?

this is my first controller:

```
define([ 'module', '{angular}/angular' ], function(module, angular) {
'use strict';

var listAnimcom = angular.module('listAnimcom', []);

listAnimcom.controller('listAnimcomCtrl', [ '$scope', 
        function($scope) {
        $scope.testAnimcom="this controller is called";           
        } ]);

return {
         angularModules : [ 'listAnimcom' ]
       };
});
```

this is my second controller where i wante to inject the first:

```
define([ 'module', '{angular}/angular',
     '{animcom}/modules/controllers/listAnimcom',
      ], function(module, angular) {
'use strict';

var plateformeDeTest = angular.module('plateformeDeTest', ['listAnimcom']);

plateformeDeTest.controller('plateformeDeTestCtrl', [ '$scope','listAnimcomCtrl',
        function($scope,listAnimcomCtrl) {
   $scope.typeActivite="polcom";
   $scope.typeClient="plateforme";

        } ]);

return {
        angularModules : [ 'plateformeDeTest' ]
       };
});
```

but it gives me this error:

```
 angular.js:12798 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.12/$injector/unpr?p0=listAnimcomCtrlProvider%20%3C-%20listAnimcomCtr... 
  at angular.js:38
```

Any idea pls !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Comment: There is a lot of questions regarding controller to controller communicatino on StackOverflow, please use the search (google will mostly find them too) before asking

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** inject one controller to another controller.

In order to share the data among the controllers, consider using **`factory/service`**.

Better to go through this answer to understand better on [`sharing data among controllers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs).

**Example using factory,**

```js
var app = angular.module("clientApp", [])
 app.controller("TestCtrl", 
   function($scope,names) {
     $scope.names =[];
    $scope.save= function(){
      names.add($scope.name);
    } 
    
  });
 app.controller("TestCtrl2", 
   function($scope,names) {
    $scope.getnames = function(){
     $scope.names = names.get();
   }
});
   
app.factory('names', function(){
  var names = {};
  names.list = [];
  names.add = function(message){
    names.list.push({message});
  };  
  names.get = function(){
    return names.list;
  };
  return names;
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html >

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="clientApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <button ng-click="save()" > save</button>
    
  </div>
  
  <div ng-init="getnames()" ng-controller="TestCtrl2">
     <div  ng-repeat="name in names">
       {{name}}
       </div>
     
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please did you have a concrete example??

Comment: @elogriamine check the demo, it shows how to share data among two controllers using factory

Comment: Thank you, it solves the problem concerning the example that I posted, but indeed in my case in which I work there is a whole business logic that is in the first controller (variable, function ..) that I want to reuse also In the second, you can say in the form of factorin, I do not see how to reuse these elements in the second controller using the services

Comment: @elogriamine Probably you can do bit of research, upvote if the answer has helped