# Click in one div close antoher div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('RedCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.OpenRed = function() {
    $scope.userRed = !$scope.userRed;
  }
  $scope.HideRed = function() {
    $scope.userRed = false;
   }  
});
app.directive('hideRed', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
       })
      $document.bind('click', function() {
       scope.$apply(attr.hideRed);
      })
    }
   }
});

app.controller('BlueCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.OpenBlue = function() {
    $scope.userBlue = !$scope.userBlue;
  };
  $scope.HideBlue = function() {
    $scope.userBlue = false;
  };  
});
app.directive('hideBlue', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
       $document.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(attr.hideBlue);
     })
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
   display:flex;
}
a
{
margin-right:20px;
}
.loginBox 
{
  z-index: 10;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}

.fontSize 
{
  font-size: 30px;
}
.loginBoxBlue
{
  z-index: 10;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="RedCtrl">
      <a href="#" ng-click="OpenRed()" hide-red="HideRed()"  ng-class="{'fontSize': userRed}">Show Red</a>
      <div hide-red="HideRed()" class="loginBox" ng-show="userRed"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="BlueCtrl">
      <a href="#" ng-click="OpenBlue()" hide-blue="HideBlue()"  ng-class="{'fontSize': userBlue}">Show Blue</a>
      <div hide-blue="HideBlue()" class="loginBoxBlue" ng-show="userBlue"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hey, In this script you can click on `Show Red` and `Show Blue` and show red and blue boxes. You can close these boxes click in outside or click again on text. If you click in both text two divs will show.

Question: How do that if I click in `Show Red` blue box hide and if I click `Show Blue` red box hide. I would like that only one box could show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wonder why did you implement two controllers? It just complicated your simple app. Use one `RedCtrl` instead, so there's no problem with communication between variables.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('RedCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.OpenRed = function() {
    $scope.userRed = !$scope.userRed;
    $scope.userBlue = false;
  }
  $scope.HideRed = function() {
    $scope.userRed = false;
  }
  $scope.OpenBlue = function() {
    $scope.userBlue = !$scope.userBlue;
    $scope.userRed = false;
  };
  $scope.HideBlue = function() {
    $scope.userBlue = false;
  };
});

app.directive('hideRed', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      })
      $document.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(attr.hideRed);
      })
    }
  }
});

app.directive('hideBlue', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
      $document.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(attr.hideBlue);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.loginBox {
  z-index: 10;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}

.fontSize {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.loginBoxBlue {
  z-index: 10;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">

<body ng-controller="RedCtrl">
  <div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="OpenRed()" hide-red="HideRed()" ng-class="{'fontSize': userRed}">Show Red</a>
    <div hide-red="HideRed()" class="loginBox" ng-show="userRed"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="OpenBlue()" hide-blue="HideBlue()" ng-class="{'fontSize': userBlue}">Show Blue</a>
    <div hide-blue="HideBlue()" class="loginBoxBlue" ng-show="userBlue"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again :) because I thought if have long HTML code better is divide body on smaller controllers than use one controller in body. Maybe I am wrong :)

Comment: But in Angular in possible to comunicate between controllers at all?

Comment: @V.R It is, but may be a little bit difficult for someone who begins his adventure with angularjs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs

Comment: I try do something more advanced i.e. register and login panel with direct to home page and everything worked good until to moment when I added this script in external file. Now display error "RedCtrl" is not registered. I know you can not understand me hihi but maybe you know this problem

Comment: @V.R Would be much better if you would make a new brand question, because I have to see your problem :) Also other users will like to help you too.