# Reducing the overhead of using $emit and $broadcast in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have separate angularjs component (angularjs version 1.5.9) that is integrated in angularjs application. My component do something and i want to notify my parent application to some work on the particular action taken by the component.

**P.S. I don't want to use $emit & $broadcast events to notify the parent application.**

I'm curious to know that is there's any other way to implement this thing. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use events?

Comment: Yes, there are already many event registered on the parent .js file. I don't want to listen other events there as it will impact the performance of that page i.e load time. It is parent js file that already invoke service calls plus if i add other events to be listened then it will surely hamper the performance that is not apt.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  $emit & $broadcast events you can use event bus.

checkout the article at : http://jonathancreamer.com/an-angular-event-bus-with-postal-js/

Also check- What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?

[What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs/19498009#19498009)