# call function from another controller in a button onClick

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to click on a button and trigger a function of another controller. The important part here is that I have two controllers DashboardController where I have a datatable with a button and with a onClick I call a function of the other Controller named DashboardDeviceController.

I'm doing this so when I click on the button I will open a new view with tabs where each tab will have graphs.

So I want when I click on my button to specify the tab which it will be open instead of "Consumptions" which is the active tab by default.

```
DasboardController
```

button inside datatableoptions

```
return icon = '<center><a class="state-link" data-state-id="' + data.id + '" ng-click="setActiveTab(\"consumptions\")"><i style="color:#ff0000; width:21px; height:21px" title="Consumptions threshold exceed" class="fa fa-warning"></i></a></center>';
```

and I try to do this but didnt work..

```
$rootScope.$on("setActiveTab", function(name, obj, event){
                $scope.parentmethod(name, obj);
            });

            $scope.parentmethod = function(name, obj, event) {
                // task
                console.log("name ",name);
                var btn = event.currentTarget;
                obj[btn.id]=true;
                console.log("btn ", btn);
                activeTab = name;
            }


DashboardDeviceController

controllerScope.activeTab = {
            consumptions: true,
            network     : false,
            ap          : false,
            modem       : false,
            system      : false,
        };


controllerScope.getActiveTab = function () {
            console.log("getActiveTab()");

            var activeTab = null;
            for(var tabName in controllerScope.activeTab) {
                if (controllerScope.activeTab[tabName]) {
                    activeTab = tabName;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return activeTab;
        }

        controllerScope.setActiveTab = function (name) {
            console.log("setActiveTab()");

            var activeTab = null;
            for(var tabName in controllerScope.activeTab) {
                if (controllerScope.activeTab[tabName] == name) {
                    controllerScope.activeTab = name;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs , to have a reusable function or things, you have to create a service.

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .factory('myService', serviceFunction);

serviceFunction.$inject = [];

function serviceFunction() {
    return {
        reusableFunction1: function() {}
    };
}
```

In angularjs service (or factory) implement the buisiness logic of your application. You can have a service to manage authentication for example. After create your service(s), you can inject it in your controller to use his functions:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'myService'];

function myCtrl($scope, myService) {
    myService.reusableFunction1();
}
```

I join links to service and factory official documentation if you want to get more:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 0):

Use `BROADCAST/EMIT an ON` to communicate

```
$scope.$emit('myCustomEvent', 'Data to send');

// firing an event downwards
$scope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', {
  someProp: 'Sending you an Object!' // send whatever you want
});

// listen for the event in the relevant $scope
$scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function (event, data) {
  console.log(data); // 'Data to send'
});
```

**EXAMPLE**

plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/WemGxPytLLmPulml8xjK?p=preview

**OR**

You can use angular.extend to communicate/link between controllers

```
app.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, $controller) {
        angular.extend(this, $controller('DashboardDeviceController', {$scope: $scope}));
});
```

Comment: And then with $scope I can have access to controllerScope.getActiveTab and controllerScope.setActiveTab right? And I just need to pass an argument in my botton ng-click inside setActiveTab??

Comment: I tried to do in DashboardController var object = angular.extend(this, $controller('DashboardDeviceController', {$scope: $scope})) but object returns {}

Comment: don't assign that. you can directly use it in the main Controller. or use the broadcast/emit method. that will be easy

Comment: I tried like I said in the post to use emit and on but I cant pass the event in the button ... so I'm trying another solution

Comment: I tried to do this https://plnkr.co/edit/EMoKkM3DjlpfA9ec9ru6?p=catalogue and inside $scope I have the activeTab property with a json object inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153759/discussion-between-sibi-raj-and-andre-bastos).

Answer (score 0):

Communication between controllers is done though $emit + $on / $broadcast + $on methods.

`return icon = '<center><a class="state-link" data-state-id="' + data.id + '" ng-click="setActiveTab($event)"><i style="color:#ff0000; width:21px; height:21px" title="Consumptions threshold exceed" class="fa fa-warning"></i></a></center>';`

In the action of `setActiveTab($event)` in `DashboardController` you need to call the `DashboardDeviceController` function like below

Let's say you have

```
app.controller('DashboardDeviceController', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(){
           $scope.parentmethod();
        });

        $scope.parentmethod = function() {
            // task
        }
    }
]);
app.controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $scope.setActiveTab = function(event) {
            $rootScope.$emit("CallParentMethod", {});
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: In myb utton I want to pass the name of the tab I want to change.. and not the event i've edit my button

Comment: yes you can. you need to pass the name from your DashboardController function to DashboardDeviceController

Comment: Can we chat to explain better what I have now?? pls

Comment: How to chat in the stackoverflow with you?

Comment: by comments you can

Comment: Nop.. inside of the offical chat of stackoverflow... can you create a room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153768/discussion-between-sangram-badi-and-andre-bastos).

Answer (score 0):

The besat idea is this,
First you need to check the priority of your controller, like
They are communication :

**1.parent to child communication**

```
then do in your parent controller $scope.$broadcast('name',{objkey:value});
then do in your child controller $scope.$on('name',function(event,args){
//console the args params
});
```

**2.child to parent communication:**

```
then do in your child controller $scope.$emit('name',{objkey:value});
then do in your parent controller $scope.$on('name',function(event,args){
//console the args params
});
```