# comunication between controllers isnt working with $scope.broadcast and $scope.on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I guys, in my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070603/call-function-from-another-controller-in-a-button-onclick) I ask how to comunicate between 2 controllers, inside the same file. I have a button where I pass a name inside ng-click with a tab name. When i click in this button the goal is to open a new view in the specified tab inside ng-click.

Each controller have a view instantiated with ng-controller, so they dont share the same view.

At now I have,

dashboardController:

button inside datatable :

```
return icon = '<center><a class="state-link" data-state-id="' + data.id + '" ng-click="setActiveTab(\'system\')"><i style="color:#0040ff; width:21px; height:21px" title="System threshold exceed" class="fa fa-warning"></i></a></center>';

controllerScope.setActiveTab = function (name) {
    console.log("setActiveTab()");
    console.log("name ",name);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', name);
}
```

dashboardDeviceController:

Here I have the var i want to change

```
controllerScope.activeTab = {
    consumptions: true,
    network     : false,
    ap          : false,
    modem       : false,
    system      : false,
};

$rootScope.$on('myCustomEvent', function(event, data) {

    console.log("myCustomEvent ", data);
    for (var tabName in controllerScope.activeTab) {
       if (controllerScope.activeTab[tabName] == data) {
          controllerScope.activeTab[tabName] = data;
          break;
       }
    }
});
```

I have a problem and when I click in the button nothing happen.. so is there a problem with $rootScope.on or $rootScope.broadcast??? I cant figure this out ...

Comment: what is `controllerScope` use `$scope` to broadcast

Comment: can you create a [mcve] of the scenario you are trying to solve?  looking at the two questions together, it's not immediately obvious how your code is structured and the relationship you actually have between these two controllers. Though @Sravan is probably correct, this could be just a typo.

Comment: Don't use controllerScope use $scope. `$scope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', name)` and to receive use `$scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function(event, data){console.log(data)})` you will get name

Comment: I tried and in debug when  I click in button it doenst do anyhing.. dont print nothing

Comment: `var controllerScope = $scope;` (taken from your comment on an answer) is generally considered a bad practice.  aside from it being unnecessary, it makes your code less clear, and could potentially introduce unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Ok... But I modified and nothing worked anyway ... any ideia?

Comment: again, after reading through both this question and your other multiple times, it's still not clear what the relationship between these two controllers actually is. This is *absolutely* a case where a [mcve] with both controllers and the supporting HTML is necessary to make sense of the problem.

Comment: version of angularjs?

Comment: I cant do a example cause it will not work because I need a lot of files and directives.. I have a dahboard view in my dashboardController. My dahboard have a table with data and a button when I click it open a new view of detail info understand? So for this detail info I have a dashboardDeviceController. I need tha part of tabs that's created in this second controller, both in the same file

Comment: it's entirely possible that the controller generating the event is a child scope in the scope hierarchy, and `$scope.$emit` instead of `$scope.$broadcast` might be necessary.

Comment: sorry "I can't create an example of the problem" isn't acceptable, that makes the question off topic **immediately**, in my opinion.  It isn't necessary to recreate your code *exactly*, but not showing enough for others to try to recreate the problem without throwing random guesses isn't efficient and doesn't work for this site format.  I've *almost never* seen a problem that couldn't be recreated in http://plnkr.co, showing the ***essential parts of the problem***.

Comment: Here's the plunkr I have.. I delete functions that wanst needed for this case to dont become too extensive ... here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/3EHq89phQVRSFxuxX7Ra?p=catalogue. I'm using angular 1.3

Comment: Can you figure the problem??

Comment: don't just use plunker to drop extra code;  *the entire point* of creating a plunker is to have a **functional** example of what the problem is, for people to make changes to the code and see what effect it has.  If you press play and it doesn't show the problem in the running window, it's not a functional example.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$scope` to `broadcast` and `subscribe,

So, change `controllerScope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', name);` to `$scope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', name);`

```
controllerScope.setActiveTab = function (name) {
    console.log("setActiveTab()");
    console.log("name ",name);
    $scope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', name);
}
```

Comment: Doenst work... I click and cant enter inside $scope.on and nothing is printed on the console.. It must appear "myCustomEvent system" because I'm passing system throgh ng-click to the $scope.broadcast with setActiveTab

Comment: does your `setActiveTab` is getting called? console is getting printed?

Comment: No is not printed

Comment: so you are having an issue with the `html` of the data table as your method is not getting called.

Comment: Here's my plunkr... I use this to call setActiveTab 
    <center><a class="state-link" data-state-id="' + data.id + '" ng-click="setActiveTab(\'system\')"><i style="color:#0040ff; width:21px; height:21px" title="System threshold exceed" class="fa fa-warning"></i></a></center>'

Comment: @AndréBastos, paste the complete `html`

Comment: Could we talk in a chat? @Sravan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153847/discussion-between-sravan-and-andre-bastos).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit)

You can either broadcast on `$rootScope`, to have the whole app hear it, or if you don't want to, you need to make sure that the broadcast is meant for the $scope itself and its children. In summary, one controller should be a child of the other.

Comment: I've already done that and I click in the button and nothing happens.. in debug  i put breakpoints and nothing happens neither printed in console... I tried with rootScope